# Issues with variables while creating a php calendar class

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to create a calendar class in php and am having issues returning class variables which are defined as public.

Here is the code for my class

```
<?php 

class CalendarClass {

// property declaration

public $months = array();
public $year;
public $month;
public $day;
public $fourYear;
public $monthFirst;
public $monthMax;
public $monthVal;

private $data = array();

//My set functions

function __construct() {
    $year = date("y");;
    $month = date("n");;
    $day = date("j");;
    $fourYear = date("Y");
    $this->setDate($year, $month, $day, $fourYear);
    echo $fourYear; // echos 2012
}

//I'm not entirely sure if these 2 are set up correctly
//From what I read these are automatically called when
//you set or get variables.
public function __set($dt, $vl) {
    $this->data[$dt] = $vl;
}

public function __get($dt) {
    return $this->data[$dt];
}


//Sets the date and all other variables accordingly
//Must have in this order
//2 digit year, 1/2 digit month and day (ex: 1, 12), 4 digit year 
public function setDate($y, $m, $d, $fourY){
    $year = $y;
    $month = $m;
    $day = $d;
    $fourYear = $fourY; 

    if($day == -1){
        $month = $month - 1;
        if($month == -1){
            $month = 11;
            $fourYear--;
            $year = substr($fourYear, -2);
        }
    }elseif($day > $this->monthMax){
        $month = $month + 1;
        if($month == 12){
            $month = 11;
            $fourYear++;
            $year = substr($fourYear, -2);
        }
    }

    if($month == -1){
        $month = 11;
        $fourYear--;
        $year = substr($fourYear, -2);
    }elseif($month == 12){
        $month = 11;
        $fourYear++;
        $year = substr($fourYear, -2);
    }

    $monthFirst = $this->valueSet($year, $month, $day, $fourYear);
    $monthMax = $this->monthReturn($month, "Max");
    $monthVal = $this->monthReturn($month, "Value");
}

//Get functions
public function getYear(){
    $test = $this->year;
    echo $test; //echos nothing
    return $this->year; 
}
public function getMonth(){
    return $this->month;    
}
public function getDay(){
    return $this->day;  
}
public function getFourYear(){
    return $this->fourYear; 
}
public function getMonthFirst(){
    return $this->monthFirst;   
}
public function getMonthMax(){
    return $this->monthMax; 
}
public function getMonthVal(){
    return $this->monthVal; 
}

// method declaration

//Returns the year portion of the equation
public function year($currentYear){

    //calculating year value
    $yearTotal = 0;
    if($currentYear > 84){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 84;
    }elseif($currentYear > 56){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 56;
    }elseif($currentYear > 28){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 28;
    }else{
        $yearTotal = $currentYear;
    }
    $yearTotal = $yearTotal + floor($currentYear / 4);
    while($yearTotal > 7){
        $yearTotal = $yearTotal - 7;
    }
    return $yearTotal;
}

//Returns the month portion of the equation
public function month($currentMonth, $four_Year){
    //Calculating month value

    //$this->month;
    $monthTotal = $this->monthReturn($currentMonth, "Value");
    if((($four_Year % 4) == 0) && ($currentMonth == 0 || $currentMonth == 1)){

            $monthTotal = $monthTotal - 1;
    }
    return $monthTotal;
}

//Returns the day portion of equation
public function day($currentDay){

    //Calculating day value
    $dayTotal = $currentDay;
    while($dayTotal > 7){
        $dayTotal = $dayTotal - 7;  
    }
    return $dayTotal;
}

//Return the total value for equation(weekday 
//"0" for sunday 
//"1" for monday 
//"2" for tuesday
public function total($yearTotal, $monthTotal, $dayTotal){

    $total = $yearTotal + $monthTotal + $dayTotal;

    $fourYear = date('Y');

    if($fourYear > 1699 && $fourYear < 1800){
        $total = $total + 5;
    }
    if($fourYear > 1799 && $fourYear < 1900){
        $total = $total + 3;    
    }
    if($fourYear > 1899 && $fourYear < 2000){
        $total = $total + 1;
    }
    if($fourYear > 1999 && $fourYear < 2100){
        $total = $total + 0;
    }
    if($fourYear > 2099 && $fourYear < 2200){
        $total = $total + 2;
    }
    if($fourYear > 2099 && $fourYear < 2200){
        $total = $total + 4;
    }


    while($total > 7){
        $total = $total - 7;
    }
    return $total;
}   

//Return the Maximum amount of day in the month
//or return the month value for equation
//2nd variable should be either 
//"Max" - for maximum amount of days in month or 
//"Value" - for the month value
public function monthReturn($month, $action){
    global $months;
    $m = $month - 1;
    if($action == "Max"){
        $max = $months[$m][0];
        return $max;
    }elseif($action == "Value"){
        $value = $months[$m][1];
        return $value;
    }else{
        return -1;  
    }

}

//Get the weekday of a certain day
public function valueSet($currentYear, $currentMonth, $currentDay, $four_Year){

$y = $this->year($currentYear);
//echo $y . "<br />";
$m = $this->month($currentMonth, $four_Year);
//echo $m . "<br />";
$d = $this->day($currentDay);
//echo $d . "<br />";
$weekday = $this->total($y, $m, $d);
return $weekday;

}
    //End of class  
    }



    ?>
```

And here is the code using that class

```
    include_once("f_calendar.php"); 

    $thisMonth = new CalendarClass;

    $nextMonth = new CalendarClass;

    $prevMonth = new CalendarClass;

    $y = $thisMonth->getYear();

    $m = $thisMonth->getMonth();

    $d = $thisMonth->getDay();

    $fY = $thisMonth->getFourYear();

    $thisMonth->setDate($y, $m, $d, $fY);

    $nextMonth->setDate($y, $m + 1, "1", $fY);

    $prevMonth->setDate($y, $m - 1, "1", $fY);

    echo $thisMonth->fourYear; //echoes nothing

    $weekDay = $thisMonth->getMonthFirst();

    $testYear = $thisMonth->getYear();

    $i = $prevMonth->getMonthMax() - $weekDay;

    $totalDays = $weekDay + $thisMonth->getMonthMax();

    $totalWeeks = ceil($totalDays / 7);

    $days = $totalWeeks * 7;

    $prevMonthMax = $prevMonth->getMonthMax();

    $thisMonthMax = $thisMonth->getMonthMax();

    $nextMonthMax = $nextMonth->getMonthMax();

    ?>
```

The objects are being defined because flag echoes are output to the screen from within them.  I originally thought it would work with my own get functions but when that didn't work I started looking more into it and learned of the magic functions `__set`, `__get` but I have not followed through with those yet.  Do I have to redo most of my code to accommodate for the magic functions? or is there a simpler and easier method to go about it? Particularly with my current code and without I intend to reuse this code so I would like to make it 100% correct so I never have to redo it.

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: You're not doing anywhere _near_ enough validation of your inputs, to make sure you have valid dates.  Also, dates are usually linked with time (mostly because of date/time zones...).  There's most likely a library for this, but if there isn't (or you insist), I'd recommend looking up JodaTime (written in Java, but the math still applies).  There's also better ways to mess with Doomsdays... and `total` isn't something you can really do with a calendar/day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you never assign a value to the object attribute "fourYear" of the class.
You do it like this

```
$fourYear = 'new value';
```

You have to do it like this:

```
$this->fourYear = 'new value';
```

Please don't use the magic functions __get and __set. You don't need them here.
You need them, if you want to do something with the value before you store it.

Here is your updatet and working class:

```
<?php 

class CalendarClass {

// property declaration

public $months = array();
public $year;
public $month;
public $day;
public $fourYear;
public $monthFirst;
public $monthMax;
public $monthVal;

private $data = array();
//My set functions

function __construct() {
    $year = date("y");;
    $month = date("n");;
    $day = date("j");;
    $this->fourYear = date("Y");
    $this->setDate($year, $month, $day, $this->fourYear);
    echo $this->fourYear; // echos 2012
}

//I'm not entirely sure if these 2 are set up correctly
//From what I read these are automatically called when
//you set or get variables.


//Sets the date and all other variables accordingly
//Must have in this order
//2 digit year, 1/2 digit month and day (ex: 1, 12), 4 digit year 
public function setDate($y, $m, $d, $fourY){
    $year = $y;
    $month = $m;
    $day = $d;
    $this->fourYear = $fourY; 

    if($day == -1){
        $month = $month - 1;
        if($month == -1){
            $month = 11;
            $this->fourYear--;
            $year = substr($this->fourYear, -2);
        }
    }elseif($day > $this->monthMax){
        $month = $month + 1;
        if($month == 12){
            $month = 11;
            $this->fourYear++;
            $year = substr($this->fourYear, -2);
        }
    }

    if($month == -1){
        $month = 11;
        $this->fourYear--;
        $year = substr($this->fourYear, -2);
    }elseif($month == 12){
        $month = 11;
        $this->fourYear++;
        $year = substr($this->fourYear, -2);
    }

    $monthFirst = $this->valueSet($year, $month, $day, $this->fourYear);
    $monthMax = $this->monthReturn($month, "Max");
    $monthVal = $this->monthReturn($month, "Value");
}

//Get functions
public function getYear(){
    $test = $this->year;
    echo $test; //echos nothing
    return $this->year; 
}
public function getMonth(){
    return $this->month;    
}
public function getDay(){
    return $this->day;  
}
public function getFourYear(){
    return $this->fourYear; 
}
public function getMonthFirst(){
    return $this->monthFirst;   
}
public function getMonthMax(){
    return $this->monthMax; 
}
public function getMonthVal(){
    return $this->monthVal; 
}

// method declaration

//Returns the year portion of the equation
public function year($currentYear){

    //calculating year value
    $yearTotal = 0;
    if($currentYear > 84){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 84;
    }elseif($currentYear > 56){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 56;
    }elseif($currentYear > 28){
        $yearTotal = $currentYear - 28;
    }else{
        $yearTotal = $currentYear;
    }
    $yearTotal = $yearTotal + floor($currentYear / 4);
    while($yearTotal > 7){
        $yearTotal = $yearTotal - 7;
    }
    return $yearTotal;
}

//Returns the month portion of the equation
public function month($currentMonth, $four_Year){
    //Calculating month value

    //$this->month;
    $monthTotal = $this->monthReturn($currentMonth, "Value");
    if((($four_Year % 4) == 0) && ($currentMonth == 0 || $currentMonth == 1)){

            $monthTotal = $monthTotal - 1;
    }
    return $monthTotal;
}

//Returns the day portion of equation
public function day($currentDay){

    //Calculating day value
    $dayTotal = $currentDay;
    while($dayTotal > 7){
        $dayTotal = $dayTotal - 7;  
    }
    return $dayTotal;
}

//Return the total value for equation(weekday 
//"0" for sunday 
//"1" for monday 
//"2" for tuesday
public function total($yearTotal, $monthTotal, $dayTotal){

    $total = $yearTotal + $monthTotal + $dayTotal;

    $this->fourYear = date('Y');

    if($this->fourYear > 1699 && $this->fourYear < 1800){
        $total = $total + 5;
    }
    if($this->fourYear > 1799 && $this->fourYear < 1900){
        $total = $total + 3;    
    }
    if($this->fourYear > 1899 && $this->fourYear < 2000){
        $total = $total + 1;
    }
    if($this->fourYear > 1999 && $this->fourYear < 2100){
        $total = $total + 0;
    }
    if($this->fourYear > 2099 && $this->fourYear < 2200){
        $total = $total + 2;
    }
    if($this->fourYear > 2099 && $this->fourYear < 2200){
        $total = $total + 4;
    }


    while($total > 7){
        $total = $total - 7;
    }
    return $total;
}   

//Return the Maximum amount of day in the month
//or return the month value for equation
//2nd variable should be either 
//"Max" - for maximum amount of days in month or 
//"Value" - for the month value
public function monthReturn($month, $action){
    global $months;
    $m = $month - 1;
    if($action == "Max"){
        $max = $months[$m][0];
        return $max;
    }elseif($action == "Value"){
        $value = $months[$m][1];
        return $value;
    }else{
        return -1;  
    }

}

//Get the weekday of a certain day
public function valueSet($currentYear, $currentMonth, $currentDay, $four_Year){

$y = $this->year($currentYear);
//echo $y . "<br />";
$m = $this->month($currentMonth, $four_Year);
//echo $m . "<br />";
$d = $this->day($currentDay);
//echo $d . "<br />";
$weekday = $this->total($y, $m, $d);
return $weekday;

}
    //End of class  
    }



?>
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you all for your help.  I'm going to go through and try to update my code to include $this-> on everything but also to just clean it up and use more validation.  I included the __SET and __GET functions after everything still wasn't working but didn't realize I just didn't assign the values to the class variables properly.  I'll also look into the jodaTime and see how to use that.